# Google Drive V3 Rest API Play Video Thru Drive App

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I currently have 4 accounts connected to the Google Drive app on my phone.

I am trying to play a .mp4 file from Google Drive using the following:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(file.getFile().getWebContentLink())));
```

When I select the Google Drive app to play the file, I am presented with a list of the 4 currently connected accounts.

I already know which account the file is from. Is there any way of passing this account to the the startActivity, maybe as part of the intent?

Comment: look into a separate, PRE call to drive getting an auth token... that is how drive access to play could be broke down.  With a drive token in hand for accnt u said that u already know, you could pass it in Intent.data to the 2nd part , hoping that drive API docs have a way ( a POST, GET access ) to use the token to get a stream on which your mediaPlay can just call open(streamURI)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code it may work and let me know it worked for you or not.:)

```
    @Override
     protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .setAccountName("yourmaild@gmail.com")
               .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER) // required for App Folder sample
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

Comment: Same result as before

Comment: @ChrisRead have you added this below line                      .setAccountName("yourmaild@gmail.com")

Comment: Yes. That was the only difference to what I had before. I doubt that GoogleApiClient has anything to do with the problem. I have successfully connected to GoogleApiClient in order to access the file and get the WebContentLink. The problem is with the Google Drive app and how it processes the intent.